# discord API self bot video streaming

Tags: discord, bots

I will talk about discord self-bots.

As you know users can stream video in calls, is there any self bot library that can stream video just like original discord client?  I don't care about the language in which the library is written, I just need it to be able to broadcast video through self-bots to guild voice channels/personal calls

Yes, I know that self-bots violate the TOS of the discord.

Answer (score 1):

I found a blog post where a developer used webrtc in Node.js to get something working. Sadly cannot use a bot, so you will have to use a user account.

[Video streaming bot for Discord](https://aixxe.net/2021/04/discord-video-bot)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The Discord downloadable client uses a custom UDP + WebSocket protocol that is very similar to the Webrtc one they use in the browser version of Discord. To stream video you can just send RTP media packets via that UDP port, the exact same way that bots currently send audio.

There's a library that currently does that:
https://github.com/dank074/Discord-video-stream